# Saving Scrapy data to corresponding URL in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, screen-scraping

Currently working with Scrapy.

I have a list of URLs stored in a MySQL database. A spider visits these URLs, capture two target info (**score** and **count**). My goal is that when Scrapy finish scraping, it automatically populates the corresponding columns before it moves on to the next URL.

I'm a newbie and I can't seem to get the saving part to work correctly. The **score** and **count** are passed on to the database successfully. But it's saved as new rows instead of being associated to the source URL.

Here's my code: 
amazon_spider.py

```
import scrapy
from whatoplaybot.items import crawledScore
import MySQLdb

class amazonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "amazon"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]
    start_urls = []

    def parse(self, response):
        print self.start_urls

    def start_requests(self):
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(
                user='root',
                passwd='',
                db='scraper',
                host='127.0.0.1',
                charset="utf8",
                use_unicode=True
                )
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            'SELECT url FROM scraped;'
            )

        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        for row in rows:
            yield self.make_requests_from_url(row[0])
        conn.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        item = crawledScore()
        item['reviewScore'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="avgRating"]/span/a/span/text()').re("[0-9,.]+")[0]
        item['reviewCount'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="summaryStars"]/a/text()').re("[0-9,]+")
        yield item
```

pipelines.py

```
import sys
import MySQLdb

class storeScore(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(
            user='root',
            passwd='',
            db='scraper',
            host='127.0.0.1',
            charset="utf8",
            use_unicode=True
        )
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO scraped(score, count) VALUES (%s, %s)""", (item['reviewScore'], item['reviewCount']))
            self.conn.commit()

        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])

            return item
```

Any help and guidance will be very much appreciated.

Thank you, guys.

Comment: You need to [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) the table. Add the `URL` to your `item` so that you can use it in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow this steps:

Add a **reviewURL** field into your **crawledScore** Item:

```
class crawledScore(scrapy.Item):
    reviewScore = scrapy.Field()
    reviewCount = scrapy.Field()
    reviewURL = scrapy.Field()
```

Save **response url** into item['reviewURL']:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = crawledScore()
    item['reviewScore'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="avgRating"]/span/a/span/text()').re("[0-9,.]+")[0]
    item['reviewCount'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="summaryStars"]/a/text()').re("[0-9,]+")
    item['reviewURL'] = response.url
    yield item
```

Finally, on your pipelines file, insert or update depending on your logic:

INSERT:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    try:
        self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO scraped(score, count, url) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""", (item['reviewScore'], item['reviewCount'], item['reviewURL']))
        self.conn.commit()
    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])

        return item
```

UPDATE:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE scraped SET score=%s, count=%s WHERE url=%s""", (item['reviewScore'], item['reviewCount'], item['reviewURL']))
            self.conn.commit()
        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])

            return item
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

This worked.I noticed that amazon redirects the original URL so I had to use `item['reviewURL'] = response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])[0]`.

If you don't mind. I have one more question.

What if I want to crawl a new domain, with its own xpath. Where can I insert some sort of conditional statement? Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend to have everything in your DB. You could create a  table named "domains" with fields: domain, reviewScoreXpath, reviewCountXpath.

So you could have a row for each domain and make a query, with the domain currently being scraped in the loop, and get the corresponding XPaths.

I hope you get what I mean.

Thanks

Comment: You could still hardcode the above behavior in the Spider's code, but it will drive you crazy if the number of domains you want to scrape, increments.

Comment: This is a small personal project. I only plan to scrape around 10 domains, max. So I decided to create different spiders. I currently have 4 working. Now I'm trying to get it to work online through scrapyd. It's hard. Lol.

Comment: Great! Have you tried deploying your Spiders on ScrapyCloud? If not, try it :)